# Does Carlo emit a "console" event?

Tags: puppeteer

Does [Carlo](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/carlo) emit a 'console' event like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-console)?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly but you can get the underlying puppeteer `page` which does, like this:

```
const app = await carlo.launch(...)
const window = app.mainWindow();
const page = window.page_;

page.on('console', () => {
  ...
})
```